# Unable to start Apache?

Tags: apache

I've tried several links with different proposals on how to fix this. At first it seems like port 80 is blocked. However, I get two different issues when I run apache in 2 different ways:

The first way:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Gives me error:

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                                  /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.0.0.1:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

The second way:

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Gives me error:

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                      (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

Notice in the one example it's referring to 0.0.0.0 whereas the other is referring to 127.0.0.1.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that something else is already linked to port 80 on your machine preventing anything else from binding to that port.

Become aware of all Include directives in your httpd.conf and remove all Listen duplicates.